# Encrypted ID to 3rd party application

Tags: database, encryption

I would like to ask you a question that arose these days with GDPR new rules. What I have is a payments service which use BrainTree to make the payments. In our side we store some information including the ID of the user. The problem is that we should not send the original User ID to Braintree directly and we need an ID alias instead. What do you think that is the best way to do it? To encrypt is somehow or generate a second ID in my database?

Answer (score 1):

Please add one new column with Unique reference(Alpha Numeric), which will be the unique reference for payment process. and when your internal Query logic operation and manipulation will be performed by user_id.